# Unable to play the video stream from ondataavailable callback

Tags: video, html5-video, video-processing, media-source, recordrtc

I am trying to continuously play the bytes received from the RecordRTC `ondataavailable` callback using `MediaSource`

However it throws `"Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources."` from the video html element

I have the following code, what could be wrong? Does it look correct how I convert blob to arrayBuffer and feed into the buffer?

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
videoElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen);

function handleSourceOpen() {
    videoBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp8"'); // Ensure the MIME type matches your video format
    // When the buffer is updated and there's more data to append, append it
    videoBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', appendNextBuffer);
}


navigator.getUserMedia(
    {
        video: true
    },
    function (stream) {
        recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, {
            type: "video",
            mimeType: "video/webm",

            recorderType: RecordRTC.MediaStreamRecorder,

            videoBitsPerSecond: 128000,

            timeSlice: 500,

            frameInterval: 30,
            
            ondataavailable: function (blob) {
                
                // main pushing video data to my array
                accumulatedVideoBlobs.push(blob)

                if (!videoElement.paused) {
                    return;
                }

                videoElement.play()
                // At the beginning, call the function to feed the blob into the buffer
                appendNextBuffer()
            },
        });


        recordVideo.startRecording();
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);


function appendNextBuffer() {
    if (videoBuffer.updating || accumulatedVideoBlobs.length === 0) {
        shouldAppendImmediately = true;
        return;
    }
    
    const nextBlob = accumulatedVideoBlobs.shift();
    blobToArrayBuffer(nextBlob, function(arrayBuffer) {
        videoBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
    });
}

function blobToArrayBuffer(blob, callback) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        callback(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

I ran the code in Electron.js, so I have verified the video format is supported through

```
if (MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs="vp8"')) {
    console.log("Supported");
} else {
    console.log("Not Supported");
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: If this was my problem: **(1)** I would check the contents of the blob (see Blob API's `toArrayBufffer` or such option). You need to convert the blob into array and then check the byte values (numbers inside the array) to see if they represent WebM data [that is packaged in a way] ready for playback within MSE. **(2)** Save the **Blob** or **Array** as a **File** and open it inside a hex editor. Compare the general structure of that file against another WebM file that is known to play in MSE. Have you ever played a WebM using MSE successfully? If yes, does your blob have a similar structure?